# Cannot add WSDL Service Reference in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, wsdl

I am trying to work on a test web service (WSDL) project. They have given me a test url, username and Password. The documentation says that the Interface supports WS-Security (WSSE v1.0). I am not able to add the reference in Visual studio 2012 and the URL gives me 404 error.

URL: https://fofms-swt.fahcsia.gov.au/SPInterface/provider.interface

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: If you open the URL in a web browser, it also gives you 404. That means the URL given is not valid

Comment: But when you try adding the URL as Service Reference in Visual Studio Project it will give another error saying Security Node not found in Soap Message... I was told that this link works only with ws-security